# Возможно ли как-нибудь центрировать виджет QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtablewidget, центрирование

[image: Таблица не центрированная]

Делаю демонстрацию задачи. Чтобы комиссия поразилась хочу сделать все красиво. Только не могу как-либо центрировать этот каменный виджет QTableWidget. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо просто растянуть столбцы на все доступное пространство таблицы, для
этого (в коде) установите флаг равномерного растягивания ([Stretch](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum)):

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
```